# Joining two dataframes on a condition (grepl)

Tags: r, left-join, grepl, fuzzyjoin

I'm looking to join two dataframes based on a condition, in this case, that one string is inside another. Say I have two dataframes,

```
df1 <- data.frame(fullnames=c("Jane Doe", "Mr. John Smith", "Nate Cox, Esq.", "Bill Lee III", "Ms. Kate Smith"), 
                  ages = c(30, 51, 45, 38, 20))

       fullnames ages
1       Jane Doe   30
2 Mr. John Smith   51
3 Nate Cox, Esq.   45
4   Bill Lee III   38
5 Ms. Kate Smith   20

df2 <- data.frame(lastnames=c("Doe", "Cox", "Smith", "Jung", "Smith", "Lee"), 
                  ages=c(30, 45, 20, 28, 51, 38), 
                  homestate=c("NJ", "CT", "MA", "RI", "MA", "NY"))
  lastnames ages homestate
1       Doe   30        NJ
2       Cox   45        CT
3     Smith   20        MA
4      Jung   28        RI
5     Smith   51        MA
6       Lee   38        NY
```

I want to do a left join on these two dataframes on ages and the row in which `df2$lastnames` is contained within `df1$fullnames`. I thought `fuzzy_join` might do it, but I don't think it liked my `grepl`:

```
joined_dfs <- fuzzy_join(df1, df2, by = c("ages", "fullnames"="lastnames"), 
+                          match_fun = c("=", "grepl()"),
+                          mode="left")
Error in which(m) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Desired result: a dataframe identical to the first but with a "homestate" column appended. Any ideas?

Comment: I've found the solution!  Gimme a sec to type it up and explain where you went wrong

Comment: Posted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575797).  It's a quick fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TLDR

You just need to fix `match_fun`:

```
# ...
match_fun = list(`==`, stringr::str_detect),
# ...
```

---

## Background

You had the right idea, but you went wrong in your interpretation of the `match_fun` parameter in [`fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/fuzzy_join.html).  Per the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/fuzzy_join.html#heading-2), `match_fun` should be a

> Vectorized function given two columns, returning TRUE or FALSE as to whether they are a match. Can be a list of functions one for each pair of columns specified in `by` (if a named list, it uses the names in x). If only one function is given it is used on all column pairs.

## Solution

A simple correction will do the trick, with further formatting by [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/). For conceptual clarity, I've typographically aligned the `by` columns with the `function`s used to match them:

```
library(dplyr)

# ...
# Existing code
# ...

joined_dfs <- fuzzy_join(
  df1, df2,

  by        =       c("ages", "fullnames" = "lastnames"),
  #                   |----|  |-----------------------|
  match_fun =    list(`==`  , stringr::str_detect      ),
  #                   |--|    |-----------------|
  #   Match by equality ^      ^ Match by detection of `lastnames` in `fullnames`    

  mode = "left"
) %>%
  # Format resulting dataset as you requested.
  select(fullnames, ages = ages.x, homestate)
```

## Result

Given your sample data reproduced here

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  fullnames = c("Jane Doe", "Mr. John Smith", "Nate Cox, Esq.", "Bill Lee III", "Ms. Kate Smith"),
  ages = c(30, 51, 45, 38, 20)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  lastnames = c("Doe", "Cox", "Smith", "Jung", "Smith", "Lee"),
  ages = c(30, 45, 20, 28, 51, 38),
  homestate = c("NJ", "CT", "MA", "RI", "MA", "NY")
)
```

this solution should produce the following `data.frame` for `joined_dfs`, formatted as requested:

```
        fullnames ages homestate
1       Jane Doe   30        NJ
2 Mr. John Smith   51        MA
3 Nate Cox, Esq.   45        CT
4   Bill Lee III   38        NY
5 Ms. Kate Smith   20        MA
```

### Note

Because each `ages` is coincidentally a unique key, the following join on only `*names`

```
fuzzy_join(
  df1, df2,
  by = c("fullnames" = "lastnames"),
  match_fun = stringr::str_detect,
  mode = "left"
)
```

will better illustrate the behavior of matching on substrings:

```
       fullnames ages.x lastnames ages.y homestate
1       Jane Doe     30       Doe     30        NJ
2 Mr. John Smith     51     Smith     20        MA
3 Mr. John Smith     51     Smith     51        MA
4 Nate Cox, Esq.     45       Cox     45        CT
5   Bill Lee III     38       Lee     38        NY
6 Ms. Kate Smith     20     Smith     20        MA
7 Ms. Kate Smith     20     Smith     51        MA
```

## Where You Went Wrong

### Error in Type

The value passed to `match_fun` should be either (the [`symbol`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html) for) a [`function`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/function.html)

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join(
  # ...
  match_fun = grepl
  # ...
)
```

or a [`list`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/list.html) of such (`symbol`s for) `function`s:

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join(
  # ...
  match_fun = list(`=`, grepl)
  # ...
)
```

Instead of providing a `list` of `symbol`s

```
match_fun = list(=, grepl)
```

you incorrectly provided a [`vector`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/vector.html) of [`character`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/character.html) strings:

> ```
> match_fun = c("=", "grepl()")
> ```

### Error in Syntax

The user should *name* the `function`s

```
`=`
grepl
```

yet you incorrectly attempted to *call* them:

```
=
grepl()
```

Naming them will pass the `function`s *themselves* to `match_fun`, as intended, whereas calling them will pass their *return values**. In R, an operator like `=` is named using backticks: `` `=` ``.

* Assuming the calls didn't fail with errors. Here, they *would* fail.

### Inappropriate Functions

To compare two values for equality, here the `character` vectors `df1$fullnames` and `df2$lastnames`, you should use the **relational operator [`==`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Comparison.html)**; yet you incorrectly supplied the *assignment* operator [`=`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/assignOps.html).

Furthermore [`grepl()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/grep.html) is not vectorized in quite the way `match_fun` desires. While its second [argument](https://rdrr.io/r/base/grep.html#heading-2) (`x`) is indeed a vector

> a **character vector** where matches are sought, or an object which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector. Long vectors are supported.

its first [argument](https://rdrr.io/r/base/grep.html#heading-2) (`pattern`) is (treated as) a single `character` string:

> **character string** containing a regular expression (or character string for `fixed = TRUE`) to be matched in the given character vector. Coerced by `as.character` to a character string if possible. **If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used** with a warning. Missing values are allowed except for `regexpr`, `gregexpr` and `regexec`.

Thus, `grepl()` is not a

> Vectorized function given two **columns**...

but rather a `function` given one string (scalar) and one column (vector) of strings.

The answer to your prayers is not `grepl()` but rather something like **[`stringr::str_detect()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringr/man/str_detect.html)**, which is

> Vectorised over `string` and `pattern`. Equivalent to `grepl(pattern, x)`.

and which wraps [`stringi::stri_detect()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stri_detect.html).

#### Note

Since you're simply trying to detect whether a **literal** string in `df1$fullnames` contains a **literal** string in `df2$lastnames`, you don't want to accidentally treat the strings in `df2$lastnames` as [regular expression](https://rdrr.io/r/base/regex.html) *patterns*.  Now your `df2$lastnames` column is statistically unlikely to contain names with special regex characters; with the lone exception of `-`, which is interpreted literally outside of `[]`, which *are* very unlikely to be found in a name.

If you're still worried about accidental regex, you might want to consider [alternative search methods](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/about_search.html) with [`stringi::stri_detect_fixed()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stri_detect.html) or [`stringi::stri_detect_coll()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stri_detect.html).  These perform literal matching, respectively by either [byte](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/about_search_fixed.html) or ["canonical equivalence"](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/about_search_coll.html); the latter adjusts for locale and special characters, in keeping with natural language processing.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I couldn't find many examples of fuzzy_join and wasn't at all clear on the match_fun.

Comment: @JessCT Great to hear!  If this solved your problem, kindly upvote it and mark it as "accepted".  :)

Comment: And THANK YOU for this long, detailed, informative response!

Comment: It's telling me I don't have enough reputation to upvote, so I'm not sure how to mark it as accepted? If one more person upvotes my question I should have enough "reputation".

Comment: Thanks Jess, my pleasure!

Comment: As much as I like this solution it has its faults: e.g., if one a of the `fullnames` is `Smithsonian`it will be joined with `Smith`! I guess to prevent that `\\b` anchors will have to be built into the code somewhere!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @ChrisRuehlemann.  I'll look into it!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Technically, the answer currently fulfills OP's stipulation of the _" condition...that one string is inside another"_.  However, one could always transform `lastnames` into a sufficient regex via `mutate(lastnames = paste0(lastnames, "$"))`, to enforce that the `fullname` end with the `lastname`.

Comment: No that won't work as the `fullnames`do **not** always end with the `lastnames`!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Good catch! You did properly account for cases like those in your solution, so credit to you.  I think OP will need to decide which criterion is better for their purposes: **(1)** that `lastname` be contained in `fullname`; or **(2)** that `fullname` be reducible to `lastname` by certain heuristics. Either way, with (say) `"Kiefer William Frederick Dempsey George Rufus Sutherland"`, it's nearly impossible to implement logic that will pick out **(1)** whether or not the person has multiple first names, multiple middle names, and multiple last names; and **(2)** which are which.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work given your two dataframes:

**Edited** as per comment by @Greg:

The code is adpated to the data as posted; if in your actual data, there are more variants expecially to last names, such as not only `III` but also `IV`, feel free to adapt the code accordingly:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    # create new column that gets rid of strings after last name:
    lastnames = sub("\\sI{1,3}$|,.+$", "", fullnames),
    # grab last names:
    lastnames = sub(".*?(\\w+)$", "\\1", lastnames)) %>%
  # join the two dataframes:
  left_join(., df2, by = c("lastnames", "ages"))
       fullnames ages lastnames homestate
1       Jane Doe   30       Doe        NJ
2 Mr. John Smith   51     Smith        MA
3 Nate Cox, Esq.   45       Cox        CT
4   Bill Lee III   38       Lee        NY
5 Ms. Kate Smith   20     Smith        MA
```

If you want `lastnames`removed just append this after `%>%`:

```
select(-lastnames)
```

**EDIT #2**:

If you don't trust the above solution given massive variation in how last names are actually noted, then of course `fuzzy_join` is an option too. **BUT**, the current `fuzzy_join` solution is not enough; it needs to be amended by one critical data transformation. This is because `str_detect` detects whether a string is **contained** within another string. That is, it will return TRUE if it compares, for example, `Smith` to `Smithsonian` or to `Hammer-Smith` - each time the string `Smith` is indeed contained in the longer names. If, as will likely be the case in a large dataset, `Smith` and `Smithsonian` happen to have the same `ages` the mismatch will be perfect: `fuzzy_join` will incorrectly join the two. The same problem arises when you have, e.g., `Smith` and `Smith-Klein` of the same age: there too `fuzzy_join` will join them.

The first set of problematic cases can be resolved by including word boundary achors `\\b` in `df2`. These assert that, for example, `Smith` must be bounded by word boundaries to either side, which is not the case with `Smithsonian`, which does have an invisible boundary to the left of `Smithsonian` but the right-hand anchor is after its last letter `n`. The second set of problematic cases can be addressed by including a negative lookahead after `\\b`, namely `\\b(?!-)`, which asserts that after the word boundary there must not be a hyphen.

The solution is easily implemented with `mutate` and `paste0` like so:

```
fuzzy_join(
  df1, df2 %>%
    mutate(lastnames = paste0("\\b", lastnames, "\\b(?!-)")),
  by  = c("ages", "fullnames" = "lastnames"),
  match_fun = list(`==`, str_detect),
  mode = "left"
) %>%
  select(fullnames, ages = ages.x, homestate)
```

Comment: OP is using these two criteria for a match: **(1)** that the `ages` are identical; and **(2)** that the `lastname` is a substring of the `fullname`. Indeed, `ages` and `lastnames` serve as a "key" to uniquely identify otherwise ambiguous rows like `"Smith"`. I suspect OP deliberately chose `"Mr. John Smith"` and `"Ms. Kate Smith"` to illustrate this point. However, this answer `*_join`s on the names alone, and as such, it includes extra, inaccurate rows for the `"Smith"`s. _"Desired result: a dataframe identical to the first [`df1`] but with a "homestate" column appended."_

Comment: Not to be a critic, but OP indicated `df1` and `df2` were merely illustrations of richer datasets: _"**Say** I have two dataframes"_. Yet this answer makes inextensible assumptions about last names, especially that none are [double-barreled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name). Notice how your last `mutate()` would fail in that case: `sub(".*?(\\w+)$", "\\1", c("Sacha Baron Cohen", "Catherine Zeta-Jones"))` gives us `c("Cohen", "Jones")`.  It really accounts for only a few possible suffixes: `"I"`, `"II"`, `"III"`, or anything preceded by a comma; so `"IV"` would be overlooked

Comment: I appreciate your level of detail and rigor of observation. But why not let OP judge?

Comment: Oh naturally, it is up to OP to determine which answer best addresses their question!  My second comment was more of a musing on extensibility, and it's hardly a "certainty" of any sort.  Apologies if I came across harshly.  As you can see from my answer, I'm quite verbose, and it's hard to cram both content and accurate tone into 600 characters or less; so I appreciate your polite response.

Comment: As for my first comment, I do think it still stands: the resulting output is not what OP requested, due to a missing `*_join` criterion.  However, that can easily be fixed by `left_join`ing on `by = c("lastnames", "ages")`.  :)

Comment: I've edited my solution. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Happy to help, and I appreciate the shout out!  :)

Comment: Yes, I like this solution too, but unfortunately my real data is crazy. It's government representatives and in one dataset it's written "John H Smith, D-NJ" (but not consistently, sometimes written out differently with no or different punctuation), and the other dataset is just last name, and it's 10k rows.

Comment: I understand. But I guess it would be possible to develop rules for the name variation and to come up with regex patterns that follow these rules.

Comment: Please see my updated solution, which corrects a critical omission in the `fuzzy_join` solution.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Great job integrating our contributions into a more complete solution!